# multiple select with jquery again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/69naX/1/

I click "show", next click "one", "two" etc, unclick etc. This doesnt work good. Next I click hide. This is OK.

Next I click "show" again and click "one" etc - this doesnt work. Next click "hide", next click "show" - "one" etc this works good.

Next click "hide", click "show" - click "one" etc doesn't work. This repeat all the time every two.

How can i fix it? `.live` doesn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You define handlers when you click Show. So when you click it a second time, the handlers are defined twice and what happens is equal to normally clicking twice - selecting and unselecting directly.

Clicking three times on Show will result in normally clicking three times which works (selecting - unselecting - selecting). Four times again won't, etc.

You could just move the click handlers of one, two, etc outside so that they get defined once only: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/69naX/2/.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#list').show().find('span').hide();
var sel = $("#example").val() || [];
$.each(sel, function(key, value){
    $('#'+value).show();
});
```

Working here: http://jsfiddle.net/69naX/4/